# Does $x$ have to be finite in $x=0\pmod1$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

When we have something like $x=0\pmod1$, the solution for $x$ can be given as $$x=\dots-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\dots$$

I know this goes on infinitely, but is it restricted to finite numbers, making it impossible for $x$ to be infinite?

Comment: Considering that the word "modulo" is defined in terms of remainders of division, you'll need to explain what it means to take the remainder when infinity is divided by $1$.

Comment: For your main question, yes, $\mathbb{R}$ or smaller (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$) is thedefault domain for modular arithmetic; if you want to extend it further, you need to define things carefully. However, I don't understand your last sentence - surely $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite? So $x=0$ (mod $1$) has infinitely many solutions?

Comment: @user Interesting point.  Would you agree that my solution for $x$ is correct (technically) at the least?

Comment: Number-Theory/Set-Theory definitely aren't where I'm strong, but my reasoning is that since the set of finite numbers is not infinite, it can't be, well, infinite (Cardinals).  Oops, I probably should say finite instead of real, right?

Comment: @SimpleArt The set of finite numbers **is** infinite. . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well, that is what I'm asking.  Surely it has infinitely many solutions, but that makes it confusing.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh.  :/  Well, I guess I'll be rewording my question.

Comment: The only thing that can be finite $\pmod{1}$ is $$A:=\left\{a\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}, n\in\mathbb Z: n\equiv a\pmod{1}\right\}=\emptyset$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in one of the comments, *"Considering that the word 'modulo' is defined in terms of remainders of division, you'll need to explain what it means to take the remainder when infinity is divided by 1."*

There is a precise answer to this in, for example, Thoralf Skolem's model of Peano Arithmetic incorporating infinite numbers (constructed in a ZF context without using the axiom of choice).  Since the even/odd dichotomy is satisfied for all finite numbers, it is satisfied for all numbers in Skolem's model, as well.

A better known framework of this type is Robinson's framework where one works with a hyperreal extension $\mathbb{R}\subset{}^{\ast}\mathbb{R}$ and the transfer principle allows one to extend the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ to hypernaturals ${}^{\ast}\mathbb{N}$ enjoying the same first order properties as the finite numbers by the transfer principle.